# Make ssh:// links open with PowerShell

Tags: windows-10, ssh, powershell

There is similar question, which asks for opening `ssh://` links in Putty. However, in newer Windows 10 updates we have native ssh support, which we can use in Powershell. So my question - how do we make `ssh://` links open in Powershell? As far I know, this works out of the box on Mac with iTerm.

Motivation:
We have documentation, where we have listed our servers together with ssh links to then, like `ssh://ssh -p 1234 -l root example.com`. Mac users can click on these links and opens iTerm with this command. I want the same behaviour on my Windows 10 (now I have to copy-paste this in PowerShell).

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? You have to be in an ash session to do ssh stuff. You could also do ssh before Windows 10. See: https://www.thomasmaurer.ch/2016/04/using-ssh-with-powershell/ or https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/ssh-remoting-in-powershell-core?view=powershell-6 or https://blog.techsnips.io/openssh-windows-setup/.   Win 10 bring native WSL for *nix, but you still have to enable it. https://www.howtogeek.com/336775/how-to-enable-and-use-windows-10s-built-in-ssh-commands/

Comment: @postanote I have updated question.

Comment: iTerm is a *nix shell by default as that is what Mac uses. So, not really an apples to apples comparison (no pun intended) on Windows. Your code must start an ssh explicitly then call your ssh command, no differently than calling putty. PS is used to directly call putty, then you pass the ssh command via putty, not PowerShell directly. SSH is not a default shell in Windows like it is on Mac. There is no file or exe assoc (what runs a given target ) in Windows for ssh. Hence the reason you have to start it. it is not enabled / usable by default.

Comment: @postanote On recent updates you can enable built-in SSH client on windows, you don't need Putty at all. I am using it half year already.

Comment: Yeppers, and that is what I am saying. I've used it since it was released. You do have to enable it though, regardless of whatever ssh ting you have on your Windows box. I have had several on my box including putty for years now.